# Style Angular Material Nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Nav bar in a toolbar as a header. The issue is the underline for the navbar tabs is fixed at the default pink. This is clashing with my page's colour scheme. The relevant code.

```
<div ng-controller="navCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding>
        <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
            <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
                <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/" name="home">Home</md-nav-item>
                <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/about" name="about">About</md-nav-item>
            </md-nav-bar>
        </md-toolbar>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

This is in the config for the app.

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark', 'default')
        .primaryPalette('grey')
        .warnPalette('red')
        .accentPalette('blue')
        .dark();
```

Any and all help is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to use `md-nav-bar md-nav-ink-bar` css property in your `css` file.

```
md-nav-bar md-nav-ink-bar {
  background: green;
}
```

Here is a working example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/yJaojP

Comment: All styles: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/navBar/navBar-theme.scss

Answer (score 2):

update to latest version [angular-material](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9137)

It was an issue.